# What is wrong with my loop

Tags: java

I'm a beginner Java student trying to make this code list the amount saved and interest for 8 years.  I'm trying to use a for loop for it.  It calculates the interest but only lists it for 1 year. Would appreciate any help solving this problem.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;   
import java.text.*;

public class RetirementGoal3   

{
private static DecimalFormat percentFormat = new DecimalFormat("###.##%");
private static DecimalFormat moneyFormat = new DecimalFormat("$###,###,###.00");
private static double interest;
private static double saveAmount;
private static double total;
private static int Max_Year = 8;
private static int year;
private static double totalSave;
private static double totalInterest;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
     calculateR();
}


public static double calculateR()                         
{                                   
 String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter how much money you can save annually.");
 if(result != null)
 saveAmount = Double.parseDouble(result);

 String result1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your interest rate(As a decimal)");
 if(result1 != null) 
 interest = Double.parseDouble(result1); 


 totalSave = saveAmount;

   for(year = 1; year <= Max_Year; ++ year)
   {
    totalInterest = saveAmount + saveAmount * interest;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "    If you save " + moneyFormat.format(totalSave) + " each year for " + Max_Year + " years" + "\n        With " + percentFormat.format(interest) + " Interest" + "             Without Interest" + "\n\nAfter year " + year + "  " + moneyFormat.format(totalSave) + "               " + moneyFormat.format(totalInterest));

    return total;
   } 



     return total;  
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `return` statement inside your `for` loop.  So, the first iteration returns, exiting the `for` loop right away.

You have a `return` statement already in the correct location, after the `for` loop, so all you have to do is remove the `return` statement that is inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change you loop to :

```
for(year = 1; year <= Max_Year; ++ year)
{
  totalInterest = saveAmount + saveAmount * interest;
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "    If you save " + moneyFormat.format(totalSave) + " each year for " + Max_Year + " years" + "\n        With " + percentFormat.format(interest) + " Interest" + "             Without Interest" + "\n\nAfter year " + year + "  " + moneyFormat.format(totalSave) + "               " + moneyFormat.format(totalInterest));
}
```

Remove the return. As soon as you do a return it stops execution of that function and return to the callers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(year = 1; year <= Max_Year; ++ year)
{
    totalInterest = saveAmount + saveAmount * interest;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "    If you save " + moneyFormat.format(totalSave) + " each year for " + Max_Year + " years" + "\n        With " + percentFormat.format(interest) + " Interest" + "             Without Interest" + "\n\nAfter year " + year + "  " + moneyFormat.format(totalSave) + "               " + moneyFormat.format(totalInterest));

    return total; //<-- PROBLEM

}
```

The problem is the `return` inside the loop. It executes one iteration and when it gets to the return statement it exits the loop. I guess you want to move it outside the loop.

**Update after your comment:** Try this

```
 String resultString = "";

 for(year = 1; year <= Max_Year; year++)
 {
 totalInterest = saveAmount + saveAmount * interest;

     resultString += "    If you save " + moneyFormat.format(totalSave) + 
                     " each year for " + Max_Year + " years" + "\n" +
                     "        With " + percentFormat.format(interest) + " Interest" + 
                     "             Without Interest" + "\n\nAfter year " + year + "  " + 
                     moneyFormat.format(totalSave) + 
                     "               " + moneyFormat.format(totalInterest) + "\n";

 } 
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resultString);

 return total;
}
```

Note that this will display things the way you want to but i think your calculations go wrong somewhere.

Comment: I want to thank all of you for that loop problem but it's not listing all 8 years in a single pane.

Comment: How many years does it show? Try changing this `for(year = 1; year <= Max_Year; ++ year)` to this `for(year = 1; year <= Max_Year; year++)`

Comment: It brings up a single pane for each year instead of listing all 8 in a single pane.  Example year 1 pane hit enter new pane is year 2 etc., I'm thinking I need the to nest the current for loop inside another for loop.

Comment: Tried that and every time you hit enter, it just adds a line until it gets to 8 times.  Trying to get a list of 8 years at once.

Comment: Ehm? Where do you hit the enter? Ok you lost me. Please update the question and provide, and be thorough about it, an expected output. Because right now i am not sure what you want

Comment: Eventually the program will list the savings with and without interest for 8 years.  I'm building it step by step and adding in what I need as I go along.  I was having trouble getting the loop to print all 8 years at once.  Example:  If you saved 3000 for 8 years \n without interest         with interest  \n year 1  3000    3100 \n  year 2  6000   6200 etc until year 8.